# Different currency converter for different object

Tags: security, opportunity, multi-currency

This due to different currency rates being used to show the converted amounts.

If an Opportunity stage is Won / Cancelled / Not Selected any currency conversions uses a dated currency rate, which is based on the decision date.  Whereas for the products selections, currency conversions use the current exchange rate.
Like below example....
Products Selection:
today’s currency rate $->£   0.603773585  -->  £->$   1.656249999741211

so £165 000 000 * 1.656249999741211 = $273 281 249.9572998

Opportunity:

Currency Rate on Opp  uses currency on decision date 31/10/2012  = $->£ 0.620713199

£165 000 000 * 1/0.620713199 = $265 823 250.1996466

The difference is due to different currency rates being used to show the converted amounts, the dated currency rate (based on decision date)vs the current exchange rate on the product selection related list.

We need consistency with both objects. We need to match the value of both the field to avoid the confusion for reporting.

Any help on this issue is highly appreciated!!!

Comment: Hi. Can you include some more information on how/where you are reporting on these figures? Maybe include an example report? That will help in determining the best solution.

Comment: there is a related list PS on Opportunity object.Field AUM in opportunity is sum of the AUM field value in the related list of all record.But the value of currency are calculating differently in two object. In opportunity we have Dated exchange currency rate which consider the deceision date.And in PS object it takes the current exchange rate.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not possible out-of-the-box. There's an idea you can vote for here: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BpUrAAK

Answer (score 1):

This is a known limitation of SF.

A workaround with triggers is described here:
http://www.force2b.net/index.php/2009/01/sfc-multi-currency-improvement/

Answer (score 0):

You could try having a custom setting (of type List) and put the currency iso codes as Name (unique), then have a helper decimal field with your custom currency rate. You won't be able to write a formula that references this setting I think (only hierarchical ones are supported from what I remember) but you'll be able to access the values in Apex without having to query for them which is always a nice thing...

The person who updates currencies will have to remember to modify the custom setting too and you'll need some kind of batch process to cascade down the change :/